# R connecting Postgres

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm just trying to connect R to PostgreSQL, but I get an error

```
library("RPostgreSQL")
m <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(m)
```

the error is

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect user@localhost:5432 on dbname "user": FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
)
```

It looks like access issue to me, but don't know how to resolve if any one can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database driver needs more information: the address of the database server, the database name, which "role" (i.e. user) you can connect to the database with, and the associated password. Do you know all those?

A good setup is to collect and store all those parameters in a [pg service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html), labeled with an easy-to-type "service" name. For example:

```
[xyz]
host=<hostname or ip>
dbname=<database>
user=<role>
password=<password>
```

Then you can create a connection in R using the service name alone:

```
library('RPostgreSQL')
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname = 'postgres://@/?service=xyz')
```

Save the pg service file in the correct path (`~/.pg_service.conf` on linux). You can include separate blocks for each service/database you use, so this file shouldn't live in a particular project's directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your credentials in your call do `dbConnect`. Here is an example

```
mydb <- dbConnect(m, user="rprimer", password="PASSword",                   
                  dbname="rprimer", host="192.168.1.151")
```

Try specifying all the necessary information and see if that helps. You'll need to adapt all the arguments to your setup.

Comment: Do not use this solution if you share or publish your code. You invite unauthorized users to access the database by giving out your password.

Comment: I fully agree with @Ian. If you share that information with others it is a security risk